# Multi level project reference using dll

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, dll, wrapper

Adding multi level project reference(Project1 referenced in Project2 & Project2 is reference in Project3) allows accessing the methods/namespace of level1(i.e. Project1) in level3(i.e.Project3).

But adding a dll reference(browse dll file instead of project reference) in Project3 instead allow access to only Project2 namespace and not Project1. Why?

Below is the scenario

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 class library project (`ChildProject1`) in `Solution1`.
I need to use this class library in my .NET Core app (.NET 6.0 or .NET 8.0) in `Solution2`.

The requirement is such that I need to reference it as .**NET Standard 2.0.**

Note: I couldn't convert/upgrade to NS2.0 directly since `Solution1` is a WPF application.

So I created a new project (class Lib targetting NS2.0) in `Solution1` which has project reference to `ChildProject1`. Named this new project as `ChildProjectWrapper`. Build this project and copied the dll to .NET Core app (created a new folder in my project in `Solution2` and copied only the `ChildProjectWrapper.dll`)

Now I added dll reference in `Solution2` pointing to this folder and tried to reference the method in `ChildProject1`. Obviously I could reference the `ChildProjectWrapper` namespace, but couldn't reference the methods or namespace in `ChildProject1`.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

PRI

Comment: You added a reference to a specific dll, it'll only know about that one dll.